# NestJS & Passport: Change JWT token on user password change?

Tags: jwt, passport.js, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm trying to reset/change the token (JWT) for users who changed their passwords on NestJS API with PassportJS. Here is a clean example of how this authorization works: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication.

I want to generate a new token on password change to make sure, that on every device on which the user was logged in, after password change they will get unauthorized and so logged out.

This is how I handle the password change in users service:

```
async changePassword(uId: string, password: any) {
    return await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder()
      .update(User)
      .set({ password: await bcrypt.hash(password.value, 10) })
      .where("userId = :userId", { userId: uId })
      .execute();
  }
```

There are no prebuild methods to do this I think. JwtService got only 5 methods: `decode`, `sign` (this one is used to generate a token), `signAsync`, `verify` and `verifyAsync`.

So how can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need some sort of way to invalidate the JWT that was already given to the user. As you can't just do that to a token, generally (it's stateless, it holds its own validity) you'd need to create a JWT restrictlist in a database that you check the incoming JWT against. If the JWT is in the restrictlist, reject the request. Otherwise, let it through (if it's valid of course)

Comment: Can do this but still will need to generate brand new token for this user. When I tried to, it didn't change or generated the same maybe.

Comment: How did you try to generate a new token? It should change because of a new expiration time

Comment: Uh well... I tried to reuse sign method because I couldn't found any other method to re-generate token for the same user before its expired... Any idea how to?

Comment: So long as you're calling `this.jwtService.sign()` again, it should be a new token. Using `jsonwebtoken` I got the following (apologies, code format is horrible in comments) > jwt.sign({ hello: 'world'}, 'secret');
'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIiwiaWF0IjoxNjM3Mjg3NzM1fQ.3qpQJwhwM3ISK_rsZE-VOBTiTl1VWBjffhF-uhFvjmY'
> jwt.sign({ hello: 'world'}, 'secret');
'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIiwiaWF0IjoxNjM3Mjg3NzM4fQ.EQ32vjJIBM1tCkXnhhGsHngitc1d5J-0FHtulLfTofw' these are two different tokens usng the same payload, cause of different exp time

Comment: Well you didn't change anything about expiry time in this code. Anyways here you use extra key option ('secret'), but then I would have to hold secret for every user and eventually change it when change password? x,x Because for the same key and payload, sign will provide exact the same token imo

Comment: But they don't sign to the same token. They're literally different tokens, because the expire time is different in both of them. I literally just signed two tokens at different times to show that different tokens get created

Comment: This part of token changes everytime you log in, so even blocking those versions of token will effect in loggin you out of all devices when logged out on one.

Comment: That's why you only add invalid tokens to your restrict list, right? That means you'll have to keep a running list of user tokens, like session tokens. You're basically re-creatng sessions, but using a JWT to do it

Comment: Let's say you are logged in on 2 devices. Then you logged in and out for a few times. So there are at least 2 + few valid tokens for you as user (and they just are until expire). So when you change password, you will need to block all of those tokens - so how to get complete the list of them on change password?

Comment: That's the problem with wanting to invalidate JWTs. Once you've issued it, if you didn't save it to begin with, you won't get it back unless the user sends it. So you need to save every JWT you've made for that user, and then invalidate all of them when the password changes. Like I said, you're re-creating a session authentication method, but usings JWTs for the token

Comment: Well I can change global key and then just start saving it - it's still a solution. Thank you! And maybe I will not have to that, because the case was: There were many people logged in on the same account, now they got separate accounts, and there is a need to make sure those old tokens won't work anymore. So the best thing to do is just changing global secret key for jwt (after changing new password for this account) :) Thank you for you help and making me understand. Cheers!